# Understanding of Prometheus

Tags: go, monitoring, prometheus

I would like to try [simple](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/master/examples/simple/main.go) example of using [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/).

1. I have downloaded server binaries
2. I have started [simple code](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/master/examples/simple/main.go), but with few modifications

   ```
   var addr = flag.String("listen-address", ":8080", "The address to listen on for HTTP requests.")
   func main() {
       flag.Parse()
       http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
       http.Handle("/test/{id}", myHandler(promhttp.Handler()))

       log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*addr, nil))
   }

   func myHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
       return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
           fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello, you've hit %s\n", r.URL.Path)
           next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
       })
   }
   ```

   **Questions:**

   1. I assume Prometheus is monitoring tool and I would like to monitor endpoints `metrics` and `/test/{id}` separately. Did I get the idea correctly by creating several handlers and using `promhttp.Handler()` as middleware?
   2. What else apart of quantity and latency of requests can be monitored in e.g. simple web app with database?

Comment: Prometheus only queries `/metrics` and that's the only place you'd run the `promhttp.Handler()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow up on @David Maze's answer, the default handler [`promhttp.Handler`](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp#Handler) is for reporting metrics.  (gathers from all registered handlers and reports them on request).

Unfortunately, it is not a generic http middleware that gives you any metrics out of the box.

I have seen many of go's web frameworks have some sort of community prometheus middleware ([gin's](https://github.com/zsais/go-gin-prometheus/blob/master/middleware.go)) that give metrics out of the box (latency, response code, request counts, etc).

The [go prometheus client library](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus) has examples of how to add metrics to your application.

```
var (

    httpRequests = prometheus.NewCounter(
        prometheus.CounterOpts{
            Name: "http_requests_total",
            Help: "Number of http requests.",
        },
    )
)

func init() {
    // Metrics have to be registered to be exposed:
    prometheus.MustRegister(httpRequests)
}

func myHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        httpRequests.Inc()
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello, you've hit %s\n", r.URL.Path)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

---

As for your second question lots :) Google advocates for monitoring 4 golden signals:

https://landing.google.com/sre/book/chapters/monitoring-distributed-systems.html#xref_monitoring_golden-signals

These are

- Traffic - Throughput - Counts/Time
- Latency - distribution / histogram
- Errors - HTTP Response codes/explicit error counts
- Saturation - resource queues ie if there is a goroutine pool how many goroutines are active at a given time

---

In my experie8inces it has also been helpful to have visibility of all the interactions between your appl8ication and your database (ie the 4 golden signals applied to your database):

- number of calls made to db from app
- latencies of calls made
- results (err/success) of your calls made to determine availability (success / total)
- saturation available from your db driver (https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DBStats)